# Get table size in Megabytes on mysql for selected data only

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a report like by how many Megabytes table are increasing per day for some forecasting purpose . I can easily find the size of table like below

```
SELECT 
    table_name AS `Table`, 
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME"
    AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";
```

But I am wondering how to find size for selected data only
**For example : I need to find out size in Megabytes on particular table only for last one week data**
Some Thing like below

`select *  from table where date between d1 and d2` should give size in Megabytes only for that query

Currently I am decomposing the big table to smaller table based on the conditions , for example : I am making separate table for specific period and dumping everything in that table to find out table size. I think its really bad idea

Comment: Run your query daily at the same time and store the results in a table. MySQL does not have resources to store every possible piece of information a user may wish

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sum(row_size) 
from (
  select 
    char_length(column1)+
    char_length(column2)+
    char_length(column3)+
    char_length(column4) ... <-- repeat for all columns
  as row_size 
  from your_table
) as tbl1;
```

user all column as char_length so you can get size of your query result.